# CodePipeline is failing in ECS BlueGreen CodeDeploy stage

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops, amazon-iam, aws-codepipeline, aws-code-deploy

CodePipeline which was working fine has started failing in ECS BlueGreen CodeDeploy stage with below error. However, another Pipeline with same IAM role is working fine. Checked IAM role it has proper permissions for CodeDeploy and ECS services. Can someone point out what am I missing?

[image]

Comment: Does the role have the trust relationship policy that's required for codedeploy to be able to assume the role? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/getting-started-create-service-role.html

Comment: Yes. The new role is created by AWS services during initial pipeline setup.

Answer (score 0):

It might be your Task execution role in your task definition. Does it have the `AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy` policy?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, it is awkward to admit that it was a typo. In *taskdef.json*, I had written incorrect AWS account ID, so the IAM role was trying to access CodePipeline of another account.